# Export Range From Google Spreadsheet to PDF with AppScript

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to export to a pdf file only a range of the spreadsheet.

Because i have extra cell for functions or maths that i dont want in the pdf.

There are also images in the spreadsheet that has to be in the pdf.

I did this, but it doesnt copy with format and also dont copy the images.

```
function prueba2(){

 var hojal=SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AjKcAy-bybS4dGRYZWY4Y3o0MUdJcUhiT1YyNUM3SEE");

  var hojal2=SpreadsheetApp.create("Ja");
  var hoja=hojal.getSheetByName("max");
  var hoja2=hojal2.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.clear();
  for(i=1;i<8;i++){
    Logger.log(i);
    for(j=1;j<220;j++){
    Logger.log(j);
      var valor=hoja.getRange(j,i).getValue();
    hoja2.getRange(j,i).setValue(valor);  
    }
  }


  DriveApp.createFile(hojal2);
}
```